# How to extract substring of Fortran string array using index of position?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have two files, one with two columns where I want to extract a substring from the second column; and the other file has a single column with the position used to subset the string. The first and second files look like these:

**File 1:** *file.txt*

```
 1 123456789
 2 123456789
 3 123456789
 4 123456789
 5 123456789
 6 123456789
 7 123456789
 8 123456789
 9 123456789
10 123456789
```

**File 2:** *index.txt*

```
1
3
5
7
```

In this example, the second column of the *file.txt* has 9 values without space. I would like to do a subset based on the position from the *index.txt* file.

I wrote the following program in **Fortran** that where I can subset them, but I don't know how to collapse them together so when I write them to a file they would be together without space.

**Fortran file:** *subsetFile.f90*

```
program subsetfile
  implicit none
  integer :: io,tmp,n,m,s,i,ind
  integer, dimension (:), allocatable :: vec, idx
  character(len=1000) :: arr
  character(len=1000) :: fn, fnpos
  print*, "File name:"
  read*, fn
  print*, "Position file name:"
  read*, fnpos
  open(unit=100, file=fnpos, status='old', action='read')
  n = 0
  do
    read(100,*,iostat=io)
    if (io/=0) exit
    n = n + 1
  end do
  close(unit=100)
  allocate (idx(n))
  open(unit=101, file=fnpos, status='old', action='read')
  do i=1,n
    read(101,*) idx(i)
  end do
  close(unit=101)
  s = n + 1
  open(unit=102, file=fn, status='old', action='read')
  n = 0
  do
    read(102,*,iostat=io)
    if (io/=0) exit
    n = n + 1
  end do
  close(unit=102)
  open(unit=103, file=fn, status='old', action='read')
  do
    read(103,*) tmp, arr
    m = len_trim(arr)
    exit
  end do
  close(unit=103)
  allocate (vec(m))
  open(unit=104, file = fn, status = 'old', action = 'read')
  open(unit=105, file = 'output.txt', status = 'replace')  
  do i=1,n
    read(104,*) ind, arr
    read(arr,'(*(i1))') vec
    write(105, *) ind, vec(idx)
  end do
  close(unit=104)
  close(unit=105)
  deallocate (idx, vec)
end program subsetfile
```

The following is the output I get when I run the code:

```
           1           1           3           5           7
           2           1           3           5           7
           3           1           3           5           7
           4           1           3           5           7
           5           1           3           5           7
           6           1           3           5           7
           7           1           3           5           7
           8           1           3           5           7
           9           1           3           5           7
          10           1           3           5           7
```

The following is the **desired output**:

```
 1 1357
 2 1357
 3 1357
 4 1357
 5 1357
 6 1357
 7 1357
 8 1357
 9 1357
10 1357
```

Does anyone know how can I write a file in that format, with only two columns?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should use explicit format for the output, not the list-directed format (*). You are already using the `i1` descriptor for the read. You can also use it for the `write`.

```
write(105, '(i0,5x,*(i1))') ind, vec(idx)
```

If those `vec` members may be larger than 9 and occupy more digits, use `i0` instead. Adjust other parameters as needed (e.g. fixed number of characters for the first number or the number of the spaces between the columns.

```
write(105, '(i10,1x,*(i1))') ind, vec(idx)
```

Comment: How to align the first column to the right side?

Comment: Just use some fixed width. E.g. `i10`.

Comment: Would it be possible to guess its width instead of hard-coding it?

Comment: What you mean by "guess"? You can use the `i0` for automatic width. Or you can use some very large value that surely will not be exceeded, like `i20`. Otherwise, you must find the size of the largest number yourself.

Comment: I can find the size of the largest number, but I don't know how could I pass such a variable. The program finds the number of rows and the size of the second column and puts it into a variable. I wonder if I could do the same and use this variable to write.

Comment: Well, is it necessary? It is quite a lot of hassle and probably a topic for a new question. You have to find the largest number, find out the number of digits and adjust the format string. The format string is just a string like any other, you can insert any number in it. There are questions and answers about that at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Remember that you are reading the items from a file and processing one by one so you cannot just simply look for a largest number in an array. You do not know what will come in the next read from that file. In my opinion, a fixed large-enough width is the appropriate thing to use here.

Answer (score 1):

In Fortran, each `format` for formatted I/O is a *string*: so you have complete freedom as far as how you can specify it.

In most cases, your format never changes, see it as a `PARAMETER` in your program. In fact, you can specify such parameter string in three ways:

1. Inside the read/write statement:

```
write(unit,'(xxxxx)')
```

2. as a `format` label

```
write(unit,100)
100 format(xxxxx)
```

3. as a `parameter` string

```
character(len=*), parameter :: myFmt = "(xxxxx)"
write(unit,myFmt)
```

4. as a non-parameter string. Note in both ways 1) and 2) you are just using a `character(len=*), parameter` string variable. Similarly, if your format may vary at runtime, just create an appropriate format string every time you need to use it, for example:

```
program test_formatString
        implicit none

        ! Copy user data
        integer, parameter :: vec(*) = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
        integer, parameter :: idx(*) = [1,3,5,7]

        integer :: n

        n = 12

        ! Test variable sizes of the first column vs the index columns
        write(*,myWidthFmt(2,1)) n, vec(idx)
        write(*,myWidthFmt(4,2)) n, vec(idx)
        write(*,myWidthFmt(3,3)) n, vec(idx)

        contains

        ! Function to create a format string
        character(len=15) function myWidthFmt(indWidth,vecWidth) result(fmt)
           integer, intent(in) :: indWidth,vecWidth
           write(fmt,1) min(indWidth,99),min(vecWidth,99)
           1 format('(i',i2,',1x,*(i',i2,'))')
        end function myWidthFmt

end program test_formatString
```

Comment: What do you mean by each format being a string?

Comment: I meant the same as @Vladimir F: "The format string is just a string like any other, you can insert any number in it"